# I'm kinda confused on how to make a stack. Is this way reliable?

Tags: python, stack

```
stack = ["1", "2", "3"]
stack.append("4")
stack.append("6")
stack.pop()
print (stack)
```

This is usually how I make one, but I see other types of examples here, and can't tell if I'm doing it right. Any explenations?

Comment: That's the correct way to use a list as a stack. Your code is almost identical to the example found in the docs: https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#using-lists-as-stacks

Answer (score 0):

This is from the official docs:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

5.1.1. Using Lists as Stacks
The list methods make it very easy to use a list as a stack, where the last element added is the first element retrieved (“last-in, first-out”). To add an item to the top of the stack, use append(). To retrieve an item from the top of the stack, use pop() without an explicit index. For example:

```
>>> stack = [3, 4, 5]  
>>> stack.append(6)  
>>> stack.append(7)  
>>> stack  
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7]  
>>> stack.pop()  
7  
>>> stack  
[3, 4, 5, 6]  
>>> stack.pop()  
6  
>>> stack.pop()  
5  
>>> stack  
[3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't "make a stack" this way.

In your example, you use a `list` instance as a stack, simply by limiting the number of allowed methods. It's a bit like putting a blindfold on your eyes and pretending you're blind.

`stack[i]` and `stack.insert(i, x)` shouldn't be used, for example. But `type(stack)` still returns `<class 'list'>`:

```
>>> stack = ["1", "2", "3"]
>>> stack.append("4")
>>> stack.append("6")
>>> stack.pop()
'6'
>>> stack
['1', '2', '3', '4']
>>> type(stack)
<class 'list'>
```

So this way isn't really reliable, because there's nothing to prevent you from calling a `list` instance method on your stack:

```
>>> stack.insert(0,'0')
>>> stack
['0', '1', '2', '3', '4']
```

If you want to restrict the number of methods available to your `stack` object, you could write a `Stack` wrapper around `list`:

```
class Stack:

    def __init__(self, items=[]):
        self.items = items

    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.items == []

    def push(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)

    def pop(self):
        return self.items.pop()

    def peek(self):
        return self.items[-1]

    def size(self):
        return len(self.items)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.items)


stack = Stack(["1", "2", "3"])
stack.push("4")
stack.push("6")
stack.pop()
print(stack)
# ['1', '2', '3', '4']
stack.insert(0, '0')
# AttributeError: Stack instance has no attribute 'insert'
```

Comment: Oh, okay. Thanks!